# Stomp - multiple subscriptions each with a unique handler

Tags: comet, stomp, orbited

I am using Stomp / Orbited for Comet functionality.

In order to deal with multiple channels, I end up doing this:

```
stomp.onmessageframe = function(frame) {
```

if (frame.headers['destination'] == '/thisFeed/') {
//handle thisFeed
}

if (frame.headers['destination'] == '/thatFeed/') {
//handle thatFeed
}

....which is OK, I guess.  But what if I don't know, at load time, how I want to handle a feed?  I want to be able to do something like this:

stomp.subscribe('someOtherFeed', someOtherFeedHandler);

That way, when I subscribe, I can define the handler then and only then.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with one solution, but it's so very far from pretty.

When I create the stomp message, I add a "handler" property as a header, like so in python:

```
conn.send('Frank the Wonder Llama", destination="/infoAboutLlamas/", handler='llamas')
```

Then, in the javascript:

```
    stomp.onmessageframe = function(frame) {
    window[frame.headers['handler']]() //Execute the function named by the handler
}
```

...so then, the function llamas() gets called.  I can then define (and redefine) llamas anywhere I want.

Now I'm sure this can't be the optimal solution.  I do, on the other hand, like that it gives me a bit of flexibility to specify the handler I want to use right in python.  But seriously, I'm thinking there is a better way.